# Passing Func<Service> vs. Service in constructor

Tags: c#

What is the difference between:

```
private readonly Func<IDataService> _dataServiceCreator;

public FriendDataProvider(Func<IDataService> dataServiceCreator)
{
  _dataServiceCreator = dataServiceCreator;
}

public Friend GetFriendById(int id)
{
  using (var dataService = _dataServiceCreator())
  {
    return dataService.GetFriendById(id);
  }
}
```

and

```
private readonly IDataService _dataService;

public FriendDataProvider(IDataService dataService)
{
  _dataService = dataService;
}

public Friend GetFriendById(int id)
{

    return _dataService.GetFriendById(id);
}
```

The data service used is FileDataSrvice. As i understand there are some pattern differences?

Comment: What's the difference between the number 5 and a method that returns any integer whenever you call it?

Comment: The second takes a thing to perform a task, and the first takes a thing that creates a thing to perform a task.

Comment: @LordWilmore The service isn't created in this class in either case.  The difference is purely whether the class has a single service that it always uses, or if it needs to be able to get as many services as it wants, whenever it wants one.  In neither option is a service constructed within the class without the caller being responsible for creating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `Func<IService>` lets one to delay instantiation (or deciding which of instances to use) of interface implementation to the point where it actually needed. Passing `IService` ties two instances directly for lifetime of your class.

One common usage of `Func<IService>` is to align lifetimes between different types. Often you have "current Zzzzz" of many that may or may not exist as long as service (i.e. current user, current request, current window) vs. "service that needs Zzzzz" (which can exist for whole apps lifetime) - if you pass `Func` code that constructed that `Func` can find "current" instance whenever service needs it.

I.e. in web application if `FriendDataProvider` is singleton class with application lifetime and implementation of `IDataService` is request specific then you can let you DI container to create implementation of `IDataService` on demand with `Func` version. If you simply pass implementation of `IDataService` to `FriendDataProvider` it will pick on tied to some arbitrary request and will not work correctly for subsequent requests.

Answer (score 3):

The type `Func<T>` represents a function that returns a `T`. So in the first example, each time you want to `GetFriendById`, you are creating a new service and then using that, whereas the 2nd example uses the same service every time.  If you want to avoid holding on to external resources for extended periods of time, the second one might be better.

Comment: Side note: "you are creating a new service and then using that" is not completely correct (as `Func` version can always return the same instance...)